# WebView error. Making an android app to view my website

Tags: android, webview

So I have a website with mobile version. I am trying to do an App for it.

This is my activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/webview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:scrollbars="none"/>
```

and this is my MainActivity.java class

```
package com.example.esouqbh.esouq;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import com.example.esouqbh.esouq.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//Remove title bar as we already have it in the web app
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
//Point to the content view defined in XML
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//Configure the webview setup in the xml layout
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
//Yes, we want javascript, pls.
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//Make sure links in the webview is handled by the webview and not sent to a full browser
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
//And let the fun begin
myWebView.loadUrl("http://esouqbh.com");    }}
```

for some reason when I run the app it says on my phone (Im running the APP on my phone as an emulator) 
I get this error

Web page not available

The web page at http://esouqbh.com could not be loaded as:

net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

note that my website functions perfectly with no problem if I open it from my computer browser or phone.

EDIT:: Found solution by adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

in androidmanifest.xml!

Comment: the solution by adding in androidmanifest.xml folder? what folder?

Comment: Just edited it sorry. Had to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NO, it´s not a folder, by adding :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

into you `AndroidManifest.xml` means that your application will load the page from the internet into your `WebView`

[**INTERNET permission**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET): allows applications to open network sockets.